# How to select a specific horizontal line of pixels in an image to analyze on Python?

Tags: python, spray, grayscale

I'm beginner on Python and started trying to program a code to analyze a spray image and plot a 'gray scale value' to see the spray pattern.

For a while I have this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
filepath = "flat2.jpg"
          
img = Image.open(filepath).convert('L')
    
    
WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
pix = img.load()
    
data = np.asarray(img.getdata())
data = data.reshape((HEIGHT,WIDTH))
    
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
reduced_data = data.mean(axis=0)
    
ax.plot(reduced_data)
    
plt.show()
```

However, this code analyze the entire image and I need just a specific line, like the line 329 or something. As a mitigation I tried crop the image too, but was unsucessfully.

I'm trying to do a code like the tool "plot profile" on Image J.

Obsviously I just "made" this code with a help from some users here.

[Flat fan spray image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aALQV.jpg)

[The line and imageJ plot profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1RSz.png)

Comment: Do you mean a horizontal line of pixels from the image?

Comment: Yeah. I changed the title now. Thanks

Comment: @ViniciusCarreira do you know the line of pixel you are interested in? Do you want it to work for any width of line?

Comment: `img.crop((0, 329, WIDTH, 330))` then save `img.save('temp.png')` an read again `img=Image.open('temp.png')`? But I believe it can be done via nympy without saving the temp file.

Comment: @DavidS It can be any horizontal line of pixel, like 329 or 150 etc. I can work with any width but if I select only a specific width (like just the spray in image) maybe will be better but probably more difficult

Comment: @ViniciusCarreira so you want to do it dynamically? Meaning that an image will open then you will mark the line and then it will plot the distribution?

Comment: @DavidS Basically I need to change the width depending of the spray extension. If I insert an image with large spray, it will probably be necessary increase width of the line as well. But, as YuriKhristich said I can just crop the image and put the width (300, 350, 400 etc.). The problem now is I don't understand how the crop tool works. Some value (155,65,360,270) works but another like (20,329,400,330) not.

Answer (score 0):

Since after several hours nobody supplied us with a sample of a correct efficient solution, here is the crop mitigation:

```
from PIL import Image

filepath = 'flat2.jpg'
img = Image.open(filepath).convert('L')

WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
LINE = 329         # <---- put here your desired line number

img = img.crop( (0, LINE, WIDTH, LINE+1 ) ).save('crop.png')
img = Image.open('crop.png')

# do stuff

# WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
# pix = img.load()
# etc
```

It should work but it's not exactly a correct and efficient solution at all. I believe it should be done via `numpy` etc.

As for the `crop()` function, it's a very simple thing. It just takes some rectangular area (box) from a given image. The four numbers inside the brackets (x1, y1, x2, y2) are tuple of coordinates of this box. Top-left corner (x1, y1) bottom-right corner (x2, y2). The only possible trouble is if any of this coordinates fall outside of image size.

Comment: Perfect, Yuri. I did this after several hours and it worked well. Now I'm just adjusting the graph, like try smoothing the line etc. Thanks.